# /summon ItemFrame relatively

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was trying to make some sort of color display in Minecraft.  I decided it might be nice to use colored armor in `ItemFrame`s as the pixels.  I have this working command:

```
/summon ItemFrame ~ ~ ~1 {Direction:0,TileX:362,TileY:56,TileZ:-653,Item:{id:minecraft:leather_chestplate,tag:{display:{color:255}}}}
```

It places an ItemFrame on the Command block (at `362,56,-653`) on the `+Z` side with a blue chestplate in it.  I would like to be able to have lots of pixels for the display, but the data tag can't handle something like `{Direction:0,TileX:~,TileY:~,TileZ:~,...`.

I was wondering if there was some way of making the display either have a relatively-positioned data tag or summon one frame and `/tp` it to the right location.  If this isn't possible without mods, what kind of display would have the second-most color options (other than `setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:wool [color]`) in vanilla Minecraft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question a while ago, and I lost my save file somewhere, so I'm not sure how exactly I did this, but here's basically what I did:

- Make a wall of command blocks behind any plain colored block behind a wall of trapdoors
- Program the command blocks to spawn a leather armor item on the trapdoor 2 blocks away
- Rearrange command blocks to change colors
- To refresh the screen, kill all the items on the trapdoors and power all the command blocks

  ```
  CX_   C=Command
  CX_   X=Any block
  CX_   _=Trapdoor
  ```